# Can you please translate this for me?

Tags: translation

미안해. 그동안 잘 못 챙겨줘서.

I translated this as "Sorry. For not caring all this time".

I know that subject pronouns in Korean can be confusing. But when I cross-checked this with Papago and Google, I get results as "Sorry. I haven't been able to take care of you" and "Sorry. For not taking good care of me all this time."

Would my translation be more accurate given that it is apathetic to the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has the more accurate translation. The translation is something like: "Sorry. For not being able to take care of you all this time." The 'i' is implied, but can be put into the translation.

Comment: Thank you. Just in case I want to say "Sorry for not caring all this time", can this sentence still be used? Just want to know if there is something I can do to make this sentence more generic than being addressed to a person.